# Update dependencies when installing a local package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a local package that I would like to install, and when it is installed it also updates / compares the currently installed packages against the dependencies defined in the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package. `install.packages()` can be used to install a local file when `repos = NULL`, but it doesn't update / install the dependencies accordingly. Furthermore, while `devtools::install_local()` and `devtools::install()` installs *missing* packages, it does not *update* packages according to the dependencies in the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package.

Is there a way to install a local package and have the corresponding packages be updated according to the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package - similar to how `install.packages()` works when installing packages from CRAN? I've explored other options within the `tools` and `devtools` package as well as other SO posts, but haven't found anything that quite does what I'm looking for.

I've put together a hack using `packageDescription()` and `installed.packages()` to compare the requirements of the package with what is installed and to update accordingly, but didn't know if there was a more elegant solution already out there.

Comment: The installation only installs (or complains) if a package is not available or if the version is too low. Other than that, it is generally up to the user to update to the newest. Since `update.packages()` tends to be rather global, perhaps you can submit an analagous update function for `devtools` that manually checks/installs individual packages based on the dependencies.

Comment: @r2evans Those are the conclusions I came to, and, like you mentioned, am leaning towards making a function to check for updates in conjunction with `packageDescription()`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining [`devtools::dev_package_deps()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.5/topics/package_deps) and [`devtools::update_packages()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.5/topics/update_packages) might work for you.

```
dependency_list <- devtools::dev_package_deps()
devtools::update_packages(dependency_list$package, dependencies=TRUE)
```

When called in the repo of an R package, the package dependencies are inspected
and the obsolete ones are updated.  Unlike the 'Update' button in RStudio's 'Packages' panel,
this code above will (a) update from CRAN and remote sources like GitHub and
(b) not attempt to install local packages that are unrelated to the current package.

This function only works if run inside a valid package.  It reads the dependencies enumerated in the package's
[DESCRIPTION](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) file.

We put his code inside of an [RStudio Add-In](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) and distribute it in our [OuhscMunge](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/OuhscMunge/blob/master/R/update-packages-addin.R)  package. It's helped our data science research team of ~10 people stay more consistent with each other.

And keep an eye on developments in the [remotes](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes) package, which "is a lightweight replacement of the `install_*` functions in devtools."

Comment: I tinkered with the approach you outlined, but opted against it as it doesn't compare the versions of installed packages against the versions outlined in the `DESCRIPTION` file, but rather if there are more up to date versions available in CRAN.
And thanks for the reminder of the remotes package. I came across it on `devtools`'s github site.

Comment: Gotcha, I hadn't considered that distinction.  Am I understanding you correctly? 
 ...there are scenarios where CRAN/GitHub has a newer version, but you wouldn't want to update (because the DESCRIPTION file didn't specify a newer version is required)?

Comment: Correct. If, for example, a user had `dplyr 0.7.2` installed, but only `dplyr (>= 0.7.0)` is required by the package, I wouldn't want to prompt an update simply because a newer version is available, only if it is necessary (which in this case it isn't).

Comment: For us, the cost of having different collaborators/machines on different package versions is a headache and much more expensive --compared to updating packages that might be unnecessary.  But since your tradeoffs differ from ours, I hope a good solution for your scenario is proposed.

Comment: Might I suggest the use of [`packrat`](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) for tight package version requirements?

Comment: I'm aware of packrat for package development, having read about and researched it while reading Hadley's [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), but haven't thought of using it for package usage. This is any interesting idea I'll have to explore.